# Highlight (not delete) repeat sentences or phrases

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am getting the impression that this is not possible in word but I figure if you are looking for any 3-4 words that come in the same sequence anywhere in a very long paper I could find duplicates of the same phrases.

I copy and pasted a lot of documentation from past papers and was hoping to find a simple way to find any repeated information in this 40+ page document there is a lot of different formatting but I would be willing to temporarily get rid of formatting in order to find repeated information.

Comment: It would be difficult.  In the first paragraph of your question, there are 81 3 and 4 word groups.  Imagine how many there would be in a 40+ page document.

Comment: I wonder if you could look at particular words - words longer than, say, seven letters? It might then be possible to look at the words on either side or such key words.

Comment: Would a concept similar to a [DAWG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_word_graph) help? I'm thinking searching each word group in series starting with the first word in the document (adding to the DAWG/referencing what was already added as you go, where each node is a word, not a letter) would not be impossible. You would just have to figure a way to create this structure in VBA and/or use an external DLL. I had tried something similar once, but found it to be quite a challenge using the standard libraries available.

Answer (score 18):

To highlight all duplicate sentences, you can also use `ActiveDocument.Sentences(i)`. Here is an example

**LOGIC**

**1)** Get all the sentences from the word document in an array

**2)** Sort the array

**3)** Extract Duplicates

**4)** Highlight duplicates

**CODE**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim MyArray() As String
    Dim n As Long, i As Long
    Dim Col As New Collection
    Dim itm

    n = 0
    '~~> Get all the sentences from the word document in an array
    For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Sentences.Count
        n = n + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyArray(n)
        MyArray(n) = Trim(ActiveDocument.Sentences(i).Text)
    Next

    '~~> Sort the array
    SortArray MyArray, 0, UBound(MyArray)

    '~~> Extract Duplicates
    For i = 1 To UBound(MyArray)
        If i = UBound(MyArray) Then Exit For
        If InStr(1, MyArray(i + 1), MyArray(i), vbTextCompare) Then
            On Error Resume Next
            Col.Add MyArray(i), """" & MyArray(i) & """"
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Next i

    '~~> Highlight duplicates
    For Each itm In Col
        Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
        Selection.HomeKey wdStory, wdMove
        Selection.Find.Execute itm
        Do Until Selection.Find.Found = False
            Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdPink
            Selection.Find.Execute
        Loop
    Next
End Sub

'~~> Sort the array
Public Sub SortArray(vArray As Variant, i As Long, j As Long)
  Dim tmp As Variant, tmpSwap As Variant
  Dim ii As Long, jj As Long

  ii = i: jj = j: tmp = vArray((i + j) \ 2)

  While (ii <= jj)
     While (vArray(ii) < tmp And ii < j)
        ii = ii + 1
     Wend
     While (tmp < vArray(jj) And jj > i)
        jj = jj - 1
     Wend
     If (ii <= jj) Then
        tmpSwap = vArray(ii)
        vArray(ii) = vArray(jj): vArray(jj) = tmpSwap
        ii = ii + 1: jj = jj - 1
     End If
  Wend
  If (i < jj) Then SortArray vArray, i, jj
  If (ii < j) Then SortArray vArray, ii, j
End Sub
```

**SNAPSHOTS**

**BEFORE**

[image]

**AFTER**

[image]

Comment: Nice answer, but my understanding is that the OP is looking for phrases, which may not take up a whole sentence.

Comment: In that case, OP will have to define the minimum number of words in a phrase else this will create a confusion. `This is a green apple` and `This is a green Ball`. `This is a green` being common in them :)

Comment: The OP *did* (`...looking for any 3-4 words that come in the same sequence...`) in the original question. My example allows for customization of same as well (with the passed argument `ChainLength`).

Comment: Ok. I will add that part as well :)

Answer (score 4):

I did not use my own DAWG suggestion, and I am still interested in seeing if someone else has a way to do this, but I was able to come up with this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
Dim ABC As Scripting.Dictionary
Dim v As Range
Dim n As Integer
    n = 5
    Set ABC = FindRepeatingWordChains(n, ActiveDocument)
    ' This is a dictionary of word ranges (not the same as an Excel range) that contains the listing of each word chain/phrase of length n (5 from the above example).
    ' Loop through this collection to make your selections/highlights/whatever you want to do.
    If Not ABC Is Nothing Then
        For Each v In ABC
            v.Font.Color = wdColorRed
        Next v
    End If
End Sub

' This is where the real code begins.
Function FindRepeatingWordChains(ChainLenth As Integer, DocToCheck As Document) As Scripting.Dictionary
Dim DictWords As New Scripting.Dictionary, DictMatches As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim sChain As String
Dim CurWord As Range
Dim MatchCount As Integer
Dim i As Integer

    MatchCount = 0

    For Each CurWord In DocToCheck.Words
        ' Make sure there are enough remaining words in our document to handle a chain of the length specified.
        If Not CurWord.Next(wdWord, ChainLenth - 1) Is Nothing Then
            ' Check for non-printing characters in the first/last word of the chain.
            ' This code will read a vbCr, etc. as a word, which is probably not desired.
            ' However, this check does not exclude these 'words' inside the chain, but it can be modified.
            If CurWord <> vbCr And CurWord <> vbNewLine And CurWord <> vbCrLf And CurWord <> vbLf And CurWord <> vbTab And _
                CurWord.Next(wdWord, ChainLenth - 1) <> vbCr And CurWord.Next(wdWord, ChainLenth - 1) <> vbNewLine And _
                CurWord.Next(wdWord, ChainLenth - 1) <> vbCrLf And CurWord.Next(wdWord, ChainLenth - 1) <> vbLf And _
                CurWord.Next(wdWord, ChainLenth - 1) <> vbTab Then
                sChain = CurWord
                For i = 1 To ChainLenth - 1
                    ' Add each word from the current word through the next ChainLength # of words to a temporary string.
                    sChain = sChain & " " & CurWord.Next(wdWord, i)
                Next i

                ' If we already have our temporary string stored in the dictionary, then we have a match, assign the word range to the returned dictionary.
                ' If not, then add it to the dictionary and increment our index.
                If DictWords.Exists(sChain) Then
                    MatchCount = MatchCount + 1
                    DictMatches.Add DocToCheck.Range(CurWord.Start, CurWord.Next(wdWord, ChainLenth - 1).End), MatchCount
                Else
                    DictWords.Add sChain, sChain
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next CurWord

    ' If we found any matching results, then return that list, otherwise return nothing (to be caught by the calling function).
    If DictMatches.Count > 0 Then
        Set FindRepeatingWordChains = DictMatches
    Else
        Set FindRepeatingWordChains = Nothing
    End If

End Function
```

I have tested this on a 258 page document (`TheStory.txt`) from [this source](http://www.anc.org/OANC/index.html#download), and it ran in just a few minutes.

See the `test()` sub for usage.

You will need to reference the Microsoft Scripting Runtime to use the `Scripting.Dictionary` objects. If that is undesirable, small modifications can be made to use `Collections` instead, but I prefer the `Dictionary` as it has the useful `.Exists()` method.

Comment: I am curious if your code was taking less than a minute for a 625 mb document then why offer a bounty and waste our time :) Or are you expecting a code which achieves that in 15-20 secs??

Comment: @SiddharthRout I had no intention of wasting anyone's time; I really wanted to see some different ways of doing this. I did not test the speed of my own until just now. I was planning on awarding the bounty to you, anyway! ;-)

Comment: I didn't do it for the bounty :) You can award it to Kim or to yourself . That is ok with me. I was just looking for a challenging question ;) `I did not test the speed of my own until just now.` If this is a fact then, I take my words back. I was simply curious that if your code does as you say (which I still find unbelievable) then you really don't need anyone other code ;) But seriously your code manages to find all duplicate sentences AND phrases in the 258 page document in less than a minute? Unfortunately I cannot test it as I cannot download that 625 MB heavy document.

Comment: @SiddharthRout If someone else wants to retest, I am very open to that! I ran mine twice for the same reason, but ended with similar results. I will not rule out an error terminating prematurely, but I did not use any `On Error` steps, so I would have expected a warning/dialog. I also scanned the doc and found highlights throughout, all the way to the last page. If someone does prove me wrong, then I'd like to know what I did wrong with my test (run with phrases of 5 words, which probably matters) so I don't do it again!

Comment: I think I will create a test document later and test it myself. The thing that is bothering me is that 1) You are looping through each word and I am looping through each sentence 2) I am not even doing a phrase check while you are doing a phrase check so how is it that my code is still slow... This is what is troubling me... Like I said, i will test it later.

Comment: @SiddharthRout If you do, please send/link it to me so I can try to reproduce myself!

Comment: I created a word file with 800 pages (119996 words) My macro took `1 hr 11 mins`. I am now running your macro. I was expecting your macro to finish in 10-15 mins max based on your study that it ran in less than a minute for 258 pages. It's already past 20 mins... Your macro is still running. Will keep you posted when it ends. The only change that I made to your code was `Dim MatchCount As Integer` to `Dim MatchCount As Long` as I was getting an overflow error (which is quite understandable)

Comment: Your macro just finished. `1 Hr 18 Mins`

Comment: Sample File for you to test. This is 41.8 kb - 800 pages (119996 words) The file also has mine and your macros in it that I used. http://wikisend.com/download/356770/Sample.docm

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14524/discussion-between-gaffi-and-siddharth-rout)

Comment: Tested this script and got a few false positives and phrases which were under the ChainLength. Unfortunately, I can't upload my file, but just something to be aware of. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I chose a rather lame theory, but it seems to work (at least if I got the question right cuz sometimes I'm a slow understander). 
I load the entire text into a string, load the individual words into an array, loop through the array and concatenate the string, containing each time three consecutive words.
Because the results are already included in 3 word groups, 4 word groups or more will automatically be recognized.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Find_Duplicates()

On Error GoTo errHandler

Dim pSingleLine                     As Paragraph
Dim sLine                           As String
Dim sFull_Text                      As String
Dim vArray_Full_Text                As Variant

Dim sSearch_3                       As String
Dim lSize_Array                     As Long
Dim lCnt                            As Long
Dim lCnt_Occurence                  As Long


'Create a string from the entire text
For Each pSingleLine In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    sLine = pSingleLine.Range.Text
    sFull_Text = sFull_Text & sLine
Next pSingleLine

'Load the text into an array
vArray_Full_Text = sFull_Text
vArray_Full_Text = Split(sFull_Text, " ")
lSize_Array = UBound(vArray_Full_Text)


For lCnt = 1 To lSize_Array - 1
    lCnt_Occurence = 0
    sSearch_3 = Trim(fRemove_Punctuation(vArray_Full_Text(lCnt - 1) & _
                    " " & vArray_Full_Text(lCnt) & _
                    " " & vArray_Full_Text(lCnt + 1)))

    With Selection.Find
        .Text = sSearch_3
        .Forward = True
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False

        Do While .Execute

            lCnt_Occurence = lCnt_Occurence + 1
            If lCnt_Occurence > 1 Then
                Selection.Range.Font.Color = vbRed
            End If
            Selection.MoveRight
        Loop
    End With

    Application.StatusBar = lCnt & "/" & lSize_Array
Next lCnt

errHandler:
Stop

End Sub

Public Function fRemove_Punctuation(sString As String) As String

Dim vArray(0 To 8)      As String
Dim lCnt                As Long


vArray(0) = "."
vArray(1) = ","
vArray(2) = ","
vArray(3) = "?"
vArray(4) = "!"
vArray(5) = ";"
vArray(6) = ":"
vArray(7) = "("
vArray(8) = ")"

For lCnt = 0 To UBound(vArray)
    If Left(sString, 1) = vArray(lCnt) Then
        sString = Right(sString, Len(sString) - 1)
    ElseIf Right(sString, 1) = vArray(lCnt) Then
        sString = Left(sString, Len(sString) - 1)
    End If
Next lCnt

fRemove_Punctuation = sString

End Function
```

The code assumes a continuous text without bullet points.

Comment: As I read this (did not test myself), since you are splitting on `" "`, won't words that end a sentence (or that are separated by a comma/other punctuation) not always match? Example: `"I like to do this."` vs. `"I like to do this sometimes."` (also, I'd +1 for still being a good response, but I'm out of votes for the day...)

Comment: Don't worry about the vote and you're right. I don't have access to my PC anymore since I left work, but I will write a small function tomorrow to remove punctuations from the search string.

Comment: I didn't complete the test (because it took so long), but this takes a significantly longer amount of time to complete than either mine or Sid's for a very large file (see the note on my answer). Though, it does still work jsut fine for smaller files.

Comment: That's very well possible. When thinking it over, I also probably should have used dictionaries; loading an array of 3-words strings into a dictionary, if exists -> copy into a new dictionary and limit my "find -> color" to only those strings applicable. I guess that the "exists" method from dictionaries can drastically increase performance (using keys) and perhaps the repetitive and explicit "find" is what makes it slow.