# VBA for MS word to find text in document

Tags: vba, ms-word

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11624006/1553562

How do i limit my search to a limited range of documents taken as input from the user???

Comment: Please explain by what you mean by limited range. And also will there be many documents?

Comment: i am considering the range of page no to be searched in the same documents. eg;- Start from Page no 3 End on Page no 20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will let you specify your range from Page 3 to Page 20

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim StartPage As Long, EndPage As Long

    StartPage = 3: EndPage = 20

    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=StartPage

    Set rng = Selection.Range

    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=EndPage

    rng.End = Selection.Bookmarks("\Page").Range.End

    '~~> Now you have got your range. Do the necessary action here
    With rng

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: my code runs for the whole word document...where should i put a loop saying that search only from Start Page and End page...

Comment: I tested it and it doesn't. I just tested it again. if you type `Debug.Print .Text` after `With rng` and if you step through it then you will notice that it will only print data from page 3 onwards. `where should i put a loop saying that search only from Start Page and End page...` You have to set it here `StartPage = 3: EndPage = 20`