# Highlight repeat sentences or phrases in a Word document

Tags: ms-word, duplicates

I found what looked like an answer here:

[Highlight (not delete) repeat sentences or phrases in a word document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301009/highlight-not-delete-repeat-sentences-or-phrases-in-a-word-document)

But after reading through all the code and answers, I really don't know what to do with the code or how to run it!  Is this a custom macro I can just copy/paste?  I'd love a plug and play solution to this.  Like the original author, I cut and paste a document together from several other documents, and I'm sure there are duplicate sentences and such throughout - I just want to find them easily so I can delete or reword them.  Thanks!

Comment: For instructions on using and editing macros see http://www.gmayor.com/installing_macro.htm and/or http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/installing_employing_macros.html.

Answer (score 1):

> You write macros in a part of Word that most users never see: the Visual Basic Editor (the VBE). Open the VBE by using any one of the following methods:
>
> - Press the keyboard shortcut, Alt+F11
> - Click the Visual Basic button on the Developer tab. To do that, click the File tab, and then click Options. On the Word Options dialog box, click Customize Ribbon. In the right side of the dialog box, select the Developer tab. Click OK to return to your document, and then on the Developer tab, click the Visual Basic button.
> - Add the Visual Basic command to the Quick Access Toolbar.

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff604039(v=office.14).aspx

In my experience with that thread, the [top code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11624006/5011643) seems to work mostly.

**CODE**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim MyArray() As String
    Dim n As Long, i As Long
    Dim Col As New Collection
    Dim itm
    
    n = 0
    '~~> Get all the sentences from the word document in an array
    For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Sentences.Count
        n = n + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyArray(n)
        MyArray(n) = Trim(ActiveDocument.Sentences(i).Text)
    Next
    
    '~~> Sort the array
    SortArray MyArray, 0, UBound(MyArray)
    
    '~~> Extract Duplicates
    For i = 1 To UBound(MyArray)
        If i = UBound(MyArray) Then Exit For
        If InStr(1, MyArray(i + 1), MyArray(i), vbTextCompare) Then
            On Error Resume Next
            Col.Add MyArray(i), """" & MyArray(i) & """"
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Next i
    
    '~~> Highlight duplicates
    For Each itm In Col
        Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
        Selection.HomeKey wdStory, wdMove
        Selection.Find.Execute itm
        Do Until Selection.Find.Found = False
            Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdPink
            Selection.Find.Execute
        Loop
    Next
End Sub

'~~> Sort the array
Public Sub SortArray(vArray As Variant, i As Long, j As Long)
  Dim tmp As Variant, tmpSwap As Variant
  Dim ii As Long, jj As Long

  ii = i: jj = j: tmp = vArray((i + j) \ 2)

  While (ii <= jj)
     While (vArray(ii) < tmp And ii < j)
        ii = ii + 1
     Wend
     While (tmp < vArray(jj) And jj > i)
        jj = jj - 1
     Wend
     If (ii <= jj) Then
        tmpSwap = vArray(ii)
        vArray(ii) = vArray(jj): vArray(jj) = tmpSwap
        ii = ii + 1: jj = jj - 1
     End If
  Wend
  If (i < jj) Then SortArray vArray, i, jj
  If (ii < j) Then SortArray vArray, ii, j
End Sub
```

I added the code to the ThisDocument item in the left sidebar, and then was able to run it. (I got an error about a string being too long, but it seems it still partly worked because there are now purple highlights in the document.)

n.b., it probably only works on the Windows version of Word. I had it work in Word 2016 Preview.